# async/wait: bubbleup exceptions?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

This pertains to a program that has to collect some info from a server on the web.

Question: How can I get the exceptions from GetServerResponseAsync and Check to bubble up through CheckAsync to the Main program?

As depicted here, they do not. ErrorHandler never gets hit.

My Main program:

```
....
try
{  
    Task.Run(() => CheckAsync()); 
    // bubble to here?
    ReadConfiguration();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
  // gather and handle all exceptions here
  ErrorHandler.NotifyMe(new[] { "some message" }, ErrorType.Stop); // never gets hit
}

public async Task CheckAsync()
{ 
    await GetServerResponseAsync("slm_check"); // may throw exception
    ...
    if (.....)
        throw new Exception("...");
    ... 
}

public async Task GetServerResponseAsync(string command)
{
   ...   
   // client = HttpClient() 
   using (apacheResponse = await client.GetAsync(ServerUrl + "...."))
   {      
        if (....)
            throw new Exception("Internal web server error", new Exception("Maybe MySQL server is down"));
        using (HttpContent content = apacheResponse.Content)
        {           
            if ( ....)
                throw new Exception("error message");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `await Task.Run(...)` or even better `await CheckAsync()`

Comment: Why are you calling `CheckAsync` on a background thread? Remove `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the exceptions from GetServerResponseAsync and Check to bubble up through CheckAsync to the Main program?

Use `await` to consume your tasks, instead of ignoring them.

Specifically, this line:

```
Task.Run(() => CheckAsync());
```

is getting a `Task` back from the `Task.Run` method, which is then ignored. Instead of ignoring that task, the code should be `await`ing it:

```
await Task.Run(() => CheckAsync());
```

As other commenters have pointed out, the `Task.Run` here doesn't really make sense. If your operation is asynchronous, it shouldn't need to *also* run on a background thread. Usually. :)  So if you take out the `Task.Run`, your code would look like:

```
await CheckAsync();
```

which will properly propagate the exception.